# Clipping dataframe columns using matching lengths of a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains annual data from multiple sites. Within each site, there are multiple data sources, which do not all have equal length in years. I do not know the upper and lower bounds of years ahead of time, and they are different for each site.

My data looks like:

```
Year    Site    Source    Value
1880     1         A       1.2
1881     1         A       1.4
1882     1         A       2.1
1883     1         A       2.7
1881     1         B       1.3
1882     1         B       1.8
1883     1         B       1.4
1891     2         A       1.9
1892     2         A       2.0
1893     2         A       2.1
1892     2         B       2.4
1893     2         B       2.2
```

For each site, I would like to clip the data using the source with the shortest timespan so that the data looks like:

```
Year    Site    Source    Value
1881     1         A       1.4
1882     1         A       2.1
1883     1         A       2.7
1881     1         B       1.3
1882     1         B       1.8
1883     1         B       1.4
1892     2         A       2.0
1893     2         A       2.1
1892     2         B       2.4
1893     2         B       2.2
```

My attempt so far:

```
for site in df['Site'].unique():

    A = df[df['Source'] == 'A']
    B = df[df['Source'] == 'B']

    if len(A['Year']) < len(B['Year']):
        B['Year'] = B.clip(A['Year'].min, A.['Year'].max)

    if len(B['Year']) < len(A['Year'):
        A['Year'] = A.clip(B['Year'].min, B['Year'].max)

    df[df['Source'] == 'A'] = A
    B = df[df['Source'] == 'B']
```

Produces:

```
Year    Site    Source    Value
1881     1         A       1.4
1882     1         A       2.1
1883     1         A       2.7
1881     1         B       1.3
1882     1         B       1.8
1883     1         B       1.4
1881     2         A       1.4
1882     2         A       2.1
1883     2         A       2.7
1881     2         B       1.3
1882     2         B       1.8
1883     2         B       1.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Sites are independent, they can be worked on with a function in a groupby, comparable to your outer loop.

You could write a function that processes each site, dropping the rows that fall outside the overlapping range:

```
def filter_site(site):
    # look at the lowest year for each source,
    # take the max value of them as lower bound
    lower = site.groupby("Source").Year.min().max()

    # likewise for upper bound
    upper = site.groupby("Source").Year.max().min()

    # filter with lower and upper bound
    return site[(site.Year >= lower) & (site.Year <= upper)]
```

And then apply the function on all sites:

```
df.groupby("Site", group_keys=False).apply(filter_site)
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, but when I perform a check by printing the length of the year column for each source by site, I'm still getting different lengths. If it worked correctly I would be getting the same length for each source, by site.

Comment: Is it possible that there are discontinuities in the data, years missing between lower and upper bound?

Comment: No. I have a line above this implementation that removes any 0/missing values. And a check using df.info() for each site and source does not reveal any null values

Comment: What I meant is that the ranges may not be continuous. E.g. a site/source might have 1881, 1883, 1884 (missing 1882). Then the lengths may not match.

Comment: Ah. No, the data has continuity in that sense. That is, there is data for every consecutive year within each site and source. But the beginning and end years (range) do not match

Comment: Returning to accept your answer. Found an error that was unrelated to your code. Fixed that, and now your solution works perfectly.